# How to use ListExecutions state in an AWS stepfunction

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

When I create a step function with a state ListExecutions as the below definition, I obtain:

```
There are Amazon States Language errors in your state machine definition. Fix the errors to continue.
The field "statusFilter" is not supported by Step Functions (at /States/ListExecutions/Parameters)
```

If I remove the statusFilter parameter I obtain the same error with stateMachineArn.
I can find proper documentation only for the API or CLI use not for the ListExecution as step.

The definition:

```
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "ListExecutions",
  "States": {
    "ListExecutions": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Next": "Wait",
      "Parameters": {
        "statusFilter": "RUNNING",
        "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:*******"
      },
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:sfn:listExecutions"
    },
    "Wait": {
      "Type": "Wait",
      "Seconds": 30,
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the API in a native state need to change the camelCase name of the parameters to PascalCase so in this case the parameters are:

```
{
 "StatusFilter": "RUNNING",
 "StateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:*******"
}
```